# lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel accessing ResourceServer::getOwnerId() inside filter

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I've implemented Lucade Gasperi's oAuth2 server for laravel which can be found here https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

I am trying to return the user id of the token in the `/apps/filters.php` but no value is returned. I am using this `ResourceServer::getOwnerId()`.

If I add `ResourceServer::getOwnerId()` inside  `/apps/routes.php` it will return the user id.

Here is the code

/apps/filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth_token', function(){
   exit(ResourceServer::getOwnerId());
});
```

Response:

/apps/routes.php

```
Route::post('test',  array('before' => 'oauth', function(){
    exit(ResourceServer::getOwnerId());
}));
```

Response: `4`

As you can see when I add `ResourceServer::getOwnerId()` to the Filter it doesn't return the ID.

The filter is working. If I return a random string it will return the string.

Have I missed something? Is it even possible to use `ResourceServer::getOwnerId()` inside  filters.php

Is it because the oauth is getting called after the filter?

Answer (score 0):

The value is being returned just into a different scope. Since filters happen before the route is resolved the data will not carry over. You can store that value in a session variable or put a redirect in the filter and pass it over as a param.